# Why do successive calls to ImageCapture.takePhoto() fail in my PWA?

Tags: webrtc, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

I am writing a PWA at the moment that uses the camera to do some light computer vision on successive frames from a mobile device camera. When calling `takePhoto()` a second (or sometimes 3rd time) I get the following error:  `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The associated Track is in an invalid state`.

It is noted in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/#imagecapture-methods) that when calling `takePhoto()`

> *devices MAY temporarily stop streaming data, reconfigure themselves with the appropriate photo settings, take the photo, and then resume streaming.*" It is also noted that "*If the operation cannot be completed for any reason (**for example, upon invocation of multiple takePhoto() method calls in rapid succession**), then reject p with a new DOMException whose name is UnknownError, and abort these steps*.

Why? Is there a way around this with `grabFrame()`? Will it change in the future? Is there a discussion within the Chrome team?

I note that I am able to successfully take the photos in quick succession using a Webcam attached to my PC, but NOT using the camera in my phone.

Comment: you might consider an alternative:
use getUserMedia to acquire a stream (this will be lower resolution), then attach the stream to a video object and then draw to a canvas, see https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/ for how to do so.

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks - I'm writing the result of a `grabFrame()`  into a canvas, but I'm wondering why `grabFrame()` (or your method) works when `takePhoto()` does not.  Interestingly, it comes with the same warnings about multiple invocations. https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/index.html#dom-imagecapture-grabframe

Comment: I would assume the difference is that takePhoto opens and closes the underlying camera device which is a rather "heavy" operation - in particular on mobile which matches your observation that it doesn't work as well on the phone.